# UISelectItems value not converted to enum when ValueExpression set programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, enums, el, jsf-2.2

I'm creating UISelectItems programmatically.  The value points to an array of enums.  Upon receiving request, when EL attempts to convert the value to an enum, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.  The UISelectItems value expression, inspected by setting a break point, appears to be fine.

[image: UISelectItems value expression]

Here's EnumConfig:

```
@Named
public class EnumConfig {
    public LanguageTag[] getLanguageTagValues() { return LanguageTag.values(); }
}
```

The encapsulating SelectOneMenu's value expression is shown here:

[image: SelectOneMenu value expression]

```
@Model
public class ManageUsersBean {
    public LanguageTag getLanguageTag() { return languageTag; }
    public void setLanguageTag(LanguageTag arg) { languageTag = arg; }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.enterprizr.business.model.enumeration.preference.LanguageTag.[Lio.enterprizr.business.model.enumeration.preference.LanguageTag;@5f2ad22c
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToEnum(ELSupport.java:206) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:405) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:77) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:473) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:54) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:73) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:67) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:142) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:108) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:68) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:142) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:108) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:142) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:108) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:68) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.layout.LayoutPaneRenderer.encodeBegin(LayoutPaneRenderer.java:152) [primefaces-extensions-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:78) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:68) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.layout.LayoutPaneRenderer.encodeBegin(LayoutPaneRenderer.java:152) [primefaces-extensions-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1855) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
... 36 more
```

Comment: Is this a sane usage of the `@Model` annotation (from `javax.enterprise.inject`)?

Comment: @Tiny: `@Model` is a sterotype for `@Named @RequestScoped`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expectedType` of `viewSelectItems` isn't right. It's `LanguageTag.class`, but it should instead be `LanguageTag[].class`.

Replace (the fictional)

```
createValueExpression("#{enumConfigBean.getLanguageTagValues()}", LanguageTag.class);
```

by

```
createValueExpression("#{enumConfigBean.languageTagValues}", LanguageTag[].class);
```

Comment: Much gratitude, thank you.  Regarding the finer point of how you rewrote the value expression... Because `EnumConfigBean` has no setter `setLanguageTagValues()` is it not preferable to write the value expression `#{enumConfigBean.getLanguageTagValues()}` for self-documentation for the benefit of other developers?  When I look at `#{enumConfigBean.languageTagValues}` it looks so much like a field, which in a managed bean would naturally have both getter and setter, and there is no such field `languageTagValues`, just one method `EnumConfigBean#getLanguageTagValues()`.

Comment: Ah well, I'd perhaps have used `#{enumConfigBean.languageTagValues()}`. A getter implies a field :) An alternative would be `<o:importConstants>`. Then you've a `#{LanguageTag}` mapping.